# How to choose laser galvanometers

Tags: laser, motion, mechanical

I am currently looking to purchase laser galvanometers like [this](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&hash=item19c28a1677&item=110638012023&nma=true&pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&rt=nc&si=ykIfbnG6rxMQVKB7tfa6%252BniDziU%253D) and [this](http://cgi.ebay.com/Laser-Galvo-Scanning-30Kpps-for-laser-show-light-ILDA_W0QQitemZ220550668048QQcategoryZ29944QQcmdZViewItemQQ_trksidZe11014.m263QQ_trkparmsZalgo%3DSIC%26its%3DI%26itu%3DUCI%252BIA%252BUA%252BFICS%252BUFI%252BDDSIC%26otn%3D10%26pmod%3D110638012023%26ps%3D63%26clkid%3D6562780343974550774#ht_2653wt_1168). However, as I'm not familiar with lasers, I'm not sure the criteria I should use to evaluate whether a given product is a good buy. What are your suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic. And I don't know why the _circuit_ tag was added, as there is no references to any circuits, only a product purchasing recommendations request.

Comment: Edited the tags. Have no idea what tags to add yet have people check out my question.

Comment: Generally you evaluate if something could be a good buy by figuring out if it will solve your problem.  Then you see if there seems to be any evidence of cheaper solutions, and guess if you are likely to find something enough cheaper (at applicable quantity) to justify the time spent continuing to look.  You might also do some research on the manufacturer and see if their products are viewed as reliable, reasonable to work with, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The galvanometers are rated in terms of how many different angles they can point at per second. The smaller the angle the mirror has to swing through, the more times per second it can do it, which is reflected in the specs for the second galvanometer you pointed to. For a light show application, the desired patterns and level of detail would determine both the required deflection and the number of points.

The generic component selection process is applicable here and goes something like this:

1. figure out a performance requirement for the component
2. find some components that meet the requirement
3. cheap enough? you're done!
4. too expensive? try adjusting your design to work with a cheaper version, go to 1.